# Read data from Kafka using Batch not work correctly using SpringBoot

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I using `SpringBoot` and want read data from `Kafka` using batch. My `application.yml` look like this:

```
spring:
  kafka:
    bootstrap-servers:
      - localhost:9092
    properties:
      schema.registry.url: http://localhost:8081
    consumer:
      auto-offset-reset: earliest
      max-poll-records: 50000
      enable-auto-commit: true
      key-deserializer: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
      value-deserializer: io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaAvroDeserializer
      group-id: "batch"
      properties:
        fetch.min.bytes: 1000000
        fetch.max.wait.ms: 20000
    producer:
      key-serializer: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer
      value-serializer: io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaAvroSerializer
    listener:
      type: batch
```

My listener:

```
@KafkaListener(id = "bar2", topics = "TestTopic")
public void listen(List<ConsumerRecord<String, GenericRecord>> records) {
   log.info("start of batch receive. Size::{}", records.size());
}
```

In log I see:

```
2019-10-04 11:08:19.693  INFO 2123 --- [     bar2-0-C-1] kafka.batch.demo.DemoApplication         : start of batch receive. Size::33279
2019-10-04 11:08:19.746  INFO 2123 --- [     bar2-0-C-1] kafka.batch.demo.DemoApplication         : start of batch receive. Size::33353
2019-10-04 11:08:19.784  INFO 2123 --- [     bar2-0-C-1] kafka.batch.demo.DemoApplication         : start of batch receive. Size::33400
2019-10-04 11:08:19.821  INFO 2123 --- [     bar2-0-C-1] kafka.batch.demo.DemoApplication         : start of batch receive. Size::33556
2019-10-04 11:08:39.859  INFO 2123 --- [     bar2-0-C-1] kafka.batch.demo.DemoApplication         : start of batch receive. Size::16412
```

I set the required, settings: `fetch.min.bytes` and `fetch.max.wait.ms`, but they do not give any effect.

In a log I see that a pack in the size no more than 33 thousand at any settings. I broke my mind and I don't understand why is this happening?

Comment: There's other settings like max.fetch.bytes you might want to look at

Comment: probably need to look at  this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51753883/increase-the-number-of-messages-read-by-a-kafka-consumer-in-a-single-poll/51755259#51755259

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`max.poll.records` is simply a maximum.

There are other properties that influence how many records you get

- `fetch.min.bytes` - The minimum amount of data the server should return for a fetch request. If insufficient data is available the request will wait for that much data to accumulate before answering the request. The default setting of 1 byte means that fetch requests are answered as soon as a single byte of data is available or the fetch request times out waiting for data to arrive. Setting this to something greater than 1 will cause the server to wait for larger amounts of data to accumulate which can improve server throughput a bit at the cost of some additional latency.
- `fetch.max.wait.ms`- The maximum amount of time the server will block before answering the fetch request if there isn't sufficient data to immediately satisfy the requirement given by fetch.min.bytes.

See [the documentation](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/).

There is no way to exactly control the minimum number of records (unless they are all identical in length).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I still don't understand why the pack size is always different. I saw your answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50370851/kafka-spring-batch-listener-flush-batch, and got this result at a size of 30_000:          start of batch receive. Size::2812
start of batch receive. Size::30000
start of batch receive. Size::2839
start of batch receive. Size::867 Pack sizes are always different

Comment: You need to increase the properties I mentioned if you want to wait longer for a "full" batch to be available.

Comment: Hi, @Gary Russell, I updated my question. See please. I use this settings: `fetch.min.bytes` and `fetch.max.wait.ms`, but they do not give any effect.